# How do I return a File() ActionResult as well as a View()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My MVC3 site downloads a .txt file to the user. I want the Download method of my controller to contact the business logic layer, then perform the download, then redirect to a new view that will announce the successful download. The problem is that I can return a view or a file but not both.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download(FormCollection collection)
    {

            //Contact BLL no problem

            return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Testing"), "text/plain", "Test.txt");
            //OR
            return RedirectToAction("OtherActionWithOtherView");
    }
```

I'm happy to go about this differently; any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a View page that has an HTML link to the file download action or an Embedded IFrame with src tag assigned to the file download action.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP can't do that.

Instead, return the view only, and put a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag in the view that redirects to the download.

Comment: I appreciate the help. This method was easy, but deprecated. I wound up using javascript.